# Como prohibir ciertos caracteres se peguen dentro de un input

Tags: php, javascript, input, caracteres

buen dia, por favor alguien puede decirme como puedo prohibir que peguen ciertos caracteres sobre un input.
Hizo esto para evitar su escritura, pero igual se pueden pegar.

```
<input type="text" name="inp"
onkeypress="return (
    
(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 58) || 
(event.charCode >= 64 && event.charCode <= 90) || 
(event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.keyCode == 209) || (event.keyCode == 241) )"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

El input posee un evento cuando se pega un texto desde el cortapapeles (lo mismo para cortar y copiar). Para ello, sólo necesitas establecer un *event listener* para capturar ese evento (tal y como lo has planteado en tu pregunta para el `keypress`, pero para el `paste`. Te dejo un ejemplo que captura ese evento y evita pegar el texto gracias al `preventDefault` y `stopPropagation`.

Sólo necesitarías adaptar la lógica de cuándo se deba ejecutar esa parte del if-else.

```js
function onPaste(event) {
  console.log('Paste!! ', event);
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="inp" onpaste="onPaste(event)">
```

Espero que te pueda servir, y si necesitas ayuda, utiliza los comentarios.

Comment: La pregunta pide evitar ciertos caracteres, no todos.

Comment: Correcto @Triby, de ahí que haya especificado que sólo debe adaptar la lógica para ejecutar el prevent y stop cuando lo necesite, para que más usuarios puedan entender de manera genérica el funcionamiento

Answer (score 1):

para eso tienes que escuchar un evento, en mi caso lo hago de esta forma

```
let input = document.getElementById("id_input")
input.addEventListener("paste", (e) => { //tambien puedes utilizar keydown

if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 86) 
    Alert("caracter no permitido")
})
```

no te olvides de agregar un campo id para que funcione el selector

Comment: Cuando se utiliza `addEventListener` siempre hay que recomendar el borrado del mismo, para evitar memory leaks (`removeEventListener`)

Comment: La pregunta pide evitar ciertos caracteres, no todos y tampoco eliminar todo el contenido previo.

Comment: @Sema, creo que no en todos los casos es aplicable la necesidad de eliminar eventos y, por cierto, ni siquiera lo mencionas en tu respuesta.

Comment: @Triby no lo menciono en mi respuesta porque la manera declarativa *no* lo necesita, por razones lógicas: si no haces un `addEventListener` no puedes hacer un `removeEventListener`, de ahí el especificar que ese forma debe llevarlo. De hecho, [puedes leerlo aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#memory_issues)

Comment: @Sema, definitivamente no aplica en este caso, porque no hay ciclos y, de hecho, también se considera mala práctica incluir los eventos dentro de etiquetas porque podría complicar el mantenimiento, aparte de resultar en un código [menos legible](https://dillionmegida.com/p/inline-events-vs-add-event-listeners/).